# Issue with datatables return data and format with more child data from ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am following this example:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

where everything is same except the format function: the example is just using the static table code to display more information while i am making an ajax call to get data and populate additional fields from another query, I have this ajax call getting table in console but the problem is it throws error on this :

```
row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
```

change to my function

```
function format (d,rowid) {
    var html;
    $.ajax({ 
        url:'getdata.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'id=' + id, 
        success: function(_html) {
            console.log(_html);
return _html;   
        }
    }); 
}
```

what datatables has is this;

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

this is where it should be:

```
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data(),1) ).show(); - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
```

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: `row.child(format(row.data(),rowid)).show(); - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`

Comment: Please also add the code where you are using the above line, to your question.

Comment: i updated my question where it is happening

Comment: I hope you are defining the `table` variable just like on the demo page? Because if not then the `row` will be undefined too and hence the error.

Comment: i fixed it thanks, it was nothing reated what you pointed out